# Need explanation of looping java recursion code

Tags: java

> This code is for finding the smallest number divisible by all num from 1 to 20
>   I dont understand how this code works on recursion can u pleases explain this it wil be helpful

```
static long gcd(long a, long b) 
{ 
   if(a%b != 0)  
      return gcd(b,a%b); 
   else 
      return b; 
} 

// Function returns the lcm of first n numbers 
static long lcm(long n) 
{ 
    long ans = 1;     
    for (long i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
        ans = (ans * i)/(gcd(ans, i)); 
    return ans; 
} 

// Driver program to test the above function 
public static void main(String []args)  
{ 
    long n = 20; 
    System.out.println(lcm(n)); 

}
```

Comment: Put println statements inside each function, and print all the variable values to see what the values are on each call.

Answer (score 0):

This is very mathy, but gcd stands for "greatest common denominator" and lcm stands for "lowest common multiple".

The main algorithm keeps track of the current lowest common multiple "ans", and iterates "i" from 1 to "n" which in this case is 20. It then multiplies the current value by each "i" and divides by the greatest common denominator between "ans" and "i".

The gcd() method uses [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to calculate the greatest common denominator

The reason that algorithm works is more a question for https://math.stackexchange.com/